# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

While registering a user I am getting this error.
Apparently I must be forwarded to the login page after registering the user but I am getting this error. Looks like the problem is with fetching the user.

Here is my different codes.

authAction.js

```js
export const userRegister = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/register",
  async (
    {
      name,
      role,
      email,
      password,
      phone,
      organisationName,
      address,
      hospitalName,
      website,
    },
    { rejectWithValue }
  ) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/register", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name,
          role,
          email,
          password,
          phone,
          organisationName,
          address,
          hospitalName,
          website,
        }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      if (data?.success) {
        alert("User Registered Successfully");
        window.location.replace("/login");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      if (error.message) {
        return rejectWithValue(error.message);
      } else {
        return rejectWithValue("An error occurred during registration");
      }
    }
  }
);
```

authSlice.js

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { getCurrentUser, userLogin, userRegister } from "./authActions";

const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
  ? localStorage.getItem("token")
  : null;

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  user: null,
  token,
  error: null,
};
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    // REGISTER user
    builder.addCase(userRegister.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    });
    builder.addCase(userRegister.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.user = payload.user;
    });
    builder.addCase(userRegister.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = payload;
    });
  },
});

export default authSlice;
```

authSerivce.js

```js
import { userLogin, userRegister } from "../redux/features/auth/authActions";
import store from "../redux/store";
export const handleRegister = (
  e,
  name,
  role,
  email,
  password,
  phone,
  organisationName,
  address,
  hospitalName,
  website
) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    store.dispatch(
      userRegister({
        name,
        role,
        email,
        password,
        phone,
        organisationName,
        address,
        hospitalName,
        website,
      })
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import authSlice from './features/auth/authSlice';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authSlice.reducer,
  }
})

export default store;
```

Comment: means `payload` is undefined, in `builder.addCase(userRegister.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {`

Comment: have you tried `builder.addCase(userRegister.fulfilled, (state, payload) => { console.log(paylaod);` to see what you're getting as a second argument?

Comment: It is giving undefined and I cannot figure out the reason. Actually, it is also giving the error to post through the link. The endpoint is working fine in postman but showing error while posting through the browser

Comment: so, `builder.addCase(userRegister.fulfilled, (state, payload) => { console.log(paylaod);` (note no `{}` around "payload" ... oh, wait, did you copy paste that exactly? I made a typo ... what if you `console.log(payload)` instead? what should `payload` (not `{payload}` contain?

Comment: If I am using "payload" then the request is showing fulfilled in dev tools but the user is still null only, maybe coz of this error - "POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/register 500"(it is working fine if I use it in postman) Any suggestion to overcome this

Comment: ok, to avoid confusion ...what does  `builder.addCase(userRegister.fulfilled, (state, data) => { console.log(data);` output in the console

Comment: as for your 500 error, that's a server side error - are you showing server side code?

Comment: useful to know ... `fetch` does not "reject" if the request gets a response - so, you need extra logic to check if `response.ok` is false (i.e. `response.ok` is true if the response status is 200-299, false otherwise - so, chances are you've been getting this `500` status all the time without ever noticing it in the developer tools console for some reason

Comment: the => console.log(data) is giving {type: 'auth/register/fulfilled', payload: undefined, meta: {…}}
{name: 'hrs', role: 'donar', email: 'hrs@hrs', password: '11', phone: '', …}
requested:"3dzEVwH6VVgIx1CPsiAyr"
requestStatus:"fulfilled"
[[Prototype]]: Object
payload: undefined
type: "auth/register/fulfilled"
[[Prototype]]: Object.
Ok, I am adding the extra logic

Answer (score 0):

In the `userRegister.fulfilled` reducer case the `action.payload` is undefined. `userRegister` returns values if there are errors or Promise rejections, it should also return a value if everything goes well. I'll assume the payload should be the data that was fetched.

```js
export const userRegister = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/register",
  async (body, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/register", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      if (data?.success) {
        alert("User Registered Successfully");
        window.location.replace("/login");
      }

      return data; // <-- return the fetched data
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return rejectWithValue(
        error?.message ?? "An error occurred during registration"
      );
    }
  }
);
```